# What SPARQL query will return the data from the example?

Tags: sparql, triplestore, triples

In my RDF store I have the following triples

For schema:

```
ex:animal rdf:type rdf:Class;
    rdfs:subClassof ex:Package_animal.

ex:height rdf:type rdf:Property;
    rdfs:label "height";
    rdfs:domain ex:animal.

ex:age rdf:type rdf:Property;
    rdfs:label "age";
    rdfs:domain ex:animal.

ex:NumberOfLegs rdf:type rdf:Property;
    rdfs:label "NumberOfLegs";
    rdfs:domain ex:animal.
```

For instances:

```
ex:dog rdf:type ex:animal;
    ex:height "10";
    ex:age "2";
    ex:NumberOfLegs "4".

ex:cat rdf:type ex:animal;
    ex:height "10";
    ex:age "3";
    ex:NumberOfLegs "4".
```

I want to:

1. Get properties of class `ex:animal`

```
ex:height 
ex:age
ex:NumberOfLegs
```

2. Get the instance ex:dog of class `ex:animal` with all of its properties

```
ex:dog rdf:type ex:animal
ex:dog ex:height "10"
ex:dog ex:age "2"
ex:dog ex:NumberOfLegs "4"
```

3. The SPARQL I thought was:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE
{
   ?p rdf:type rdf:Property.
   ?s ?p ?y.
   ?s rdf:type ex:dog.
}
```

Comment: what does not work with your query modulo using proper (prefixed) URIs which I suppose is just here because you consider it a sketch?

Comment: Your data is also a bit vague - besides those weird trailing ----A - you should consider proper datatypes for your number values, I would not use a string to model the number of legs or the age, use an integer here

Comment: I thought ---A made a confusion, so I revised it

Comment: I edited your question a bit more, so check if that's what you wanted to ask.

Comment: That's right. It's accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT ?propertyName ?value
WHERE
{
    ex:dog ?propertyName ?value.
}
```

will give you this result

```
propertyName    value
rdf:type        ex:animal
ex:height       "10"
ex:age          "2"
ex:NumberOfLegs "4"
```

You can bound `ex:dog` URI if you want it in the result

```
SELECT ?dog ?propertyName ?value
WHERE
{
    BIND(ex:dog as ?dog).
    ?dog rdf:type ex:animal.
    ?dog ?propertyName ?value.
}
```

which will yield

```
dog     propertyName     value
ex:dog  rdf:type         ex:animal
ex:dog  ex:height        "10"
ex:dog  ex:age           "2"
ex:dog  ex:NumberOfLegs  "4"
```

If you want to grab all properties of `ex:animal` you'd need to change your data.
***I edited your question so it contains the data shown below.***
For scheme knowledge:

```
   ex:animal rdf:type rdf:Class;
      rdfs:subClassof ex:Package_animal.

   ex:height rdf:type rdf:Property;
      rdfs:label "height";
      rdfs:domain ex:animal.

   ex:age rdf:type rdf:Property;
      rdfs:label "age";
      rdfs:domain ex:animal.

   ex:NumberOfLegs rdf:type rdf:Property;
      rdfs:label "NumberOfLegs";
      rdfs:domain ex:animal.
```

For instances knowledge:

```
   ex:dog rdf:type ex:animal;
      ex:height "10";
      ex:age "2";
      ex:NumberOfLegs "4".

   ex:cat rdf:type ex:animal;
      ex:height "10";
      ex:age "3";
      ex:NumberOfLegs "4".
```

Then you can use this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?dog ?animalPropertyName ?value
WHERE
{
    ?animalPropertyName rdfs:domain ex:animal.
    
    BIND(ex:dog as ?dog).  
    ?dog ?animalPropertyName ?value.
}
```

which will yield

```
dog     animalPropertyName  value
ex:dog  ex:height           "10"
ex:dog  ex:age              "2"
ex:dog  ex:NumberOfLegs     "4"
```